# Details of wp_localize_script

Tags: theme-development

Hi can anyone explain me about this?

```
wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'ZillaShortcodes', array('plugin_folder' => WP_PLUGIN_URL .'/zilla-shortcodes') );
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit about where you saw it?

Answer (score 1):

`wp_localize_scripts` writes content to the page in the form of a [Javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) that can be accesses by other Javascript that runs on the page. The point is to be able to pass dynamic data to the executing Javascript without having to make AJAX requests, parse the page for data (extract the post ID from class attributes, for example), or hide data on the page is some hacked together way.

The first parameter is the `slug` of a registered and enqueued script. You *have to* "hook" or associate `wp_localize_script` with another script that has been registered and enqueued and you must run `wp_localize_script` after that other script has been registered and enqueued, not before. Sequence is important.

> IMPORTANT! wp_localize_script() MUST be called after the script it's
>   being attached to has been enqueued or registered. It doesn't put the
>   localized script in a queue for later scripts.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

The second parameter is the name of the object that will printed to the page. This is the name that will be used to access the object data. You can think of it like a variable name except that you will use Javascript object syntax to access the data.

The third parameter is the actual data that the object will contain. It can be a single or a multi-dimensional array (multi as of 3.3).

All three parameters are required.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information about [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function from [this codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

I think you have taken this code from [this ZillaShortcodes plugin](http://www.themezilla.com/plugins/zillashortcodes/).

In this code wp_localize_script() function is making zilla-shortcodes plugin path available for all js scripts. The wp_localize_scrip is using 'jquery' as a handle so indirectly it is making available for all scripts which depends on jquery.

You can access the ZillaShortcodes plugin path in any js script that depends on jquery as following.

```
alert( ZillaShortcodes.plugin_folder );
```

Comment: thank you .is there any way to remove  wp_localize_script and use wp_enqueue_script?

Comment: @ashraf Why do you want to remove wp_localize_script and use wp_enqueue_script? wp_localize_script and wp_enqueue_script are two different functions used for two different functionalities.

Comment: Bcoz i want to use zilla shortcode to integrate into theme.I already done that but i have problem to add tabs also style for shortcode is not loading frontend.Will you please look at my code?

Comment: Yes i can please share pastebin link.

Comment: Yes.it is http://pastebin.com/Zz0Nhdij

Comment: And your site link?